# Create AVD for HTC Desire & Samsung Galaxy 3 on ADT v21.1

Tags: adt, android-virtual-device, samsung-mobile, htc-android

How do I create avd for HTC Desire and Samsung Galaxy 3 phones using ADT v21.1?
All advises that I found are about old ADT.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Device: 3.7" WVGA (480x800: hdpi)
Target: Android 2.3.3 - API Level 10
CPU/ABI: ARM (armeabi)
Uncheck "Hardware keyboard present"
Uncheck "Display a skin with hardware controls"
Memory Options: RAM: 576
Memory Options: VM Heap: 24
Internal Storage: 150 MiB
SD Card: Size: 4 GiB

You may want to use a a smaller SD card, and an Intel Atom System Image Target or x86 CPU/ABI for better performance despite less accurate emulation. Note that you need to have downloaded the equivalent platforms and system images in the SDK manager before this.